# Conditional token replacement in Ant

Tags: ant

I'm trying to do a token replace in an Ant build file, but only if the token is in a line that has specific content.

Sample mockup snippet from the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/someFolder/someFile1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/otherFolder/fileName.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/aFolder/file3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/someFolder/aFile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/someFolder/subfolder/anotherFile.js"></script>
<body>
<p>Stuff</p>
```

In this example, I want to append a ?timestamp to any of the js files that are coming from "somefolder".
I've tried something along these lines (actual regex is different):

```
<copy file="xyz.jsp" tofile="${staging}/jsp/Links-test.jsp">
    <filterchain>
       <linecontainsregexp>
           <regexp pattern="someFolder" />
       </linecontainsregexp>
           <replacestring from=".js" to=".js?blahblah" />               
     </filterchain>
</copy>
```

but that just results in a file with only the lines that were modified.  What flag do I need to set to keep all of the file contents? I need the entire file, just with some conditional replaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can put multiple filterchains together. Your filter chain filters out lines that contain the regular expression. What you need is a second filter chain to add it back in.

Completely untested:

```
<copy file="xyz.jsp" tofile="${staging}/jsp/Links-test.jsp">
    <filterchain>
       <linecontainsregexp>
           <regexp pattern="someFolder" />
       </linecontainsregexp>
           <replacestring from=".js" to=".js?blahblah" />               
     </filterchain>
     <filterchain>
         <linecontainsregexp negate="true">
           <regexp pattern="someFolder" />
        </linecontainsregexp>
     </filterchain>               
</copy>
```